# put data on recycleview using List<>

Tags: android

i m implementing recycleView demo, and i m stuck when i pass data using List<>

here is my Code

Glob.class where i have a string array.

```
public static String[] itemname = {

"हड्डियों के रोग के लिए घरेलू इलाज",
        "बच्चों के हरे—पीले दस्त के लिए घरेलू इलाज",
        "पित्त ज्वर के लिए घरेलू इलाज", "मलेरिया के लिए घरेलू इलाज",
        "घाव—फोड़ा के लिए घरेलू इलाज", "फोड़ा के लिए घरेलू इलाज",
        "पैर में काँटा लगना के लिए घरेलू इलाज",
        "बुखार से बचाव के लिए घरेलू इलाज", "निमोनिया का घरेलू उपचार",
        "बवासीर के घरेलू उपचार", "मधुमेह के घरेलू उपचार",
        "उक्त रक्तचाप के उपचार", "गठिया के घरेलू उपचार",
        "पथरी के रामबाण घरेलू उपाय", "नकसीर के घरेलू उपचार",
        "पेट दर्द के घरेलू उपचार", "सर दर्द के घरेलू उपचार",
        "सर्दी जुकाम से बचने के घरेलू उपचार"}
```

DisplayRecyclerView.class

```
 List<Data> data = fill_with_data() ;


    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
    Recycler_Adapter adapter = new Recycler_Adapter(mContext,data);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

}

public List<Data> fill_with_data() {
    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0;i<Glob.itemname.length;i++) {
        data.add(new Data(Glob.itemname[i]));

    }
    return data;
}
```

Data.class

```
public class Data {
public static String title;

public Data(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}}
```

Recycle_adapter.class

```
public class Recycler_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<View_Holder> {
Context context;
List<Data> list = Collections.emptyList();
public Recycler_Adapter(Context context, List<Data> list) {
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public View_Holder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_lauoyt, parent, false);
    View_Holder holder = new View_Holder(v);
    return holder;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(View_Holder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(list.get(position).title);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
public void insert(int position, Data data) {
    list.add(position, data);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}
public void remove(Data data) {
    int position = list.indexOf(data);
    list.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

}

working fine but printing only one data everytime.
here is my screenshot
[image]

help me plz..give me suggestion.. thank you in advance

Comment: What about your Recycler_Adapter? The adapter must define size, each element with his position and if you want to show each element in a Layout. More info: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Comment: check my adapter.. nd tell me what i missing

Comment: Please show your `View_Holder` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do have a static member instead of instance member in your `Data` class ?

Remove `static` from your `String title` in the `Data` class.

That should solve your issue as I can't seem to find any other issue from quick look at your code. Having it as `Static` made only one global copy of that `title`, thus leading to same `String` everywhere.

Comment: i dont know.. why i used static there.. now its working fine...  thank you so much ... you save my time